# Suggest a method to solve $y + y' + y'' = ry - ry^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck with the following differential equation:

$$y+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{dy}{dx} = ry - ry^2$$

where $r$ is a real positive constant and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since it is for a small research purpose, I wish to get a proper analytic solution that is not a series expansion.

I tried multiplying with $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and simplifying. This gave:

$$\frac{d}{dx} {\left(\frac{1}{2}{y'}^2-\frac{r-1}{2}y^2+ \frac{r}{3}y^3\right)}=-{y'}^2$$

But I'm unable to continue. Just to mention I also tried solving the first order equation:

$$y+ \frac{dy}{dx} = ry - ry^2$$

and tried similar solutions. That didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx=-u$ brings your ODE to an Abel equation of the second kind in normal (canonical?) form
\begin{align}
u\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dy}=u+(r-1)y-ry^2.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Via my cheat sheet http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0124.pdf I can tell you that you'll be hard pressed to get an analytical solution to Eqn. (1). I've also tried my hand at solving it to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Maple does not find a closed-form solution.  This makes it quite likely that the general solution can't be expressed in closed form.  There are of course two constant solutions:
$y = 0$ and $y = 1 - 1/r$.